# XQuery - Retrieve only a part of information

Tags: filter, limit, xquery

I work with XQuery to do statistics. I have one document like this :

```
<tr>
  <td>Element 1</td>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Element 2</td>
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Element 3</td>
  <td>40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Element 4</td>
  <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Element 5</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
```

And want to retrieve only a part of this document : I want to have only **80% of the sum of the number of element** (The Pareto distribution in fact).

In this case, I have a total of 240 elements. I want in my output the first elements so that the total of the elements is 192 (240*80/100).

In this example, the ideal output would have only the first three elements, like this :

```
<tr>
  <td>Element 1</td>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Element 2</td>
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Element 3</td>
  <td>40</td>
</tr>
```

I hope I'm clear :s. I am looking for long time, without success, I don't find how to do...

Thank so much

Comment: Sorry, but I, for one, am not clear.  If you want the total of the elements to be 192, why would you choose the 1st 3 elements, whose total is 100 + 80 + 40 = 220?  Perhaps you could clarify what type of filter you want to apply to these 5 nodes?  (Also, one confusing thing about your question is that "element" has a specific meaning in XML, and it's not clear if your use of "element" is in the XML sense, or if it's in a different sense.)

Comment: I had trouble understanding this question too.

Comment: I choose the 1st 3 elements because if I choose the 1st 2 element, the total is 180, which is below 80%, but it's not very important (an output with only this 2 elements it's correct too).

Comment: If you don't like the name of my elements 'element',  replace them with 'tagazoc', it's just for this example (really bad choice I agree...)
I just want that in the output, the sum of the 'tagazoc' tag is 80% of the real total...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
   for $total in sum(/*/*/td[2]),
        $pareto in $total*80 div 100,
        $i in 1 to count(/*/*)
      return
        if(sum(/*/*[position() le $i]/td[2]) ge $pareto
         and
           sum(/*/*[position() lt $i]/td[2]) lt $pareto
           )
           then /*/*[position() le $i]
           else ()
```

**When this XPath expression (yes this is an XQuery expression that is also an XPath 2.0 expression) is evaluated against the provided XML (wrapped into a single tope element to be made a well-formed XML document):**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Element 1</td>
        <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Element 2</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Element 3</td>
        <td>40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Element 4</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Element 5</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tr>
    <td>Element 1</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Element 2</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Element 3</td>
    <td>40</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wo, very powerful...
Just one thing, why did you declare the variable "total" and "Pareto" in the for loop?
It's not the same if they are declared before?

Comment: @WaZaA: In XQuery these two ways of defining the variables are equivalent (if the values given to them is non-sequence). In XPath 2.0 the only way to define a variable is by using a "for" expression -- "let" expressions become possible only in XPath 3.0). As I wanted to produce a pure XPath 2.0 expression, I had to define the variables using a "for" expression.